# After installing Xcode 5, getting error on launch

Tags: iphone, xcode5

I lately have been using the Xcode 5 preview to develop for ios 7. Since I have in stalled the final version, my app hasn't been running.  When the app begins to load, I get this...

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

This is my error message-

2013-09-21 16:30:33.117 App Name[6039:60b] -[AppDelegate window]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15e70080
2013-09-21 16:30:33.128 App Name[6039:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AppDelegate window]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15e70080'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2d488e8b 0x377826c7 0x2d48c7b7 0x2d48af55 0x2d3d9e98 0x60c1d 0x2fc7f425 0x2fc7ee6b 0x2fc794b9 0x2fc13be7 0x2fc12edd 0x2fc78ca1 0x320f476d 0x320f4357 0x2d45377f 0x2d45371b 0x2d451ee7 0x2d3bc541 0x2d3bc323 0x2fc77f43 0x2fc731e5 0x74cd5 0x37c7bab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: What's the actual error message?

Comment: Please post some log messages. That will help to determine the cause

Comment: When you get this it is normally a memory access issue. It is caught in method main and is why it is showing. There is something going on with  your code. What does the terminal/error log say?

Comment: try to add the exceptional breakpoint and see where the app crashes exactly. hope this helps.

Comment: here, I added the output above @BergQuester

Comment: Here, I added it above @optme

Comment: Are you using NIB files or Storyboards? I had this issue when I used NIBs in XCode5 DP

Comment: I'm just coding programmatically (No Story Board or XIBs)@Anil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message **-[AppDelegate window]: unrecognized selector sent to instance** indicates that your appDelegate class is missing the required UIWindow *window property. Your appDelegate header file should look like this at a minimum:

```
 @interface AnyNameAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
 @property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
 @end
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much, I had accidently commented it out(How stupid of me)@bneely